# Is there a specification for versioning a dataset?

Tags: metadata

In computer software, [semantic versioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) (or something like it) is something of a standard for how to version software releases. The `Major.Minor.Patch` semantics make clear how big of a change has occurred between the present and an earlier release. Is there something similar for versionining a dataset? Unlike with software, any change to a dataset might be a "major" change, so I'm not sure that the logic translates directly. Is there any commonly used specification for versioning a dataset?

Comment: I wonder if the dat folks have thought about this http://dat-data.com/ max ogden & co. - I don't know, but i imagine they'd have some insight here.

Comment: BTW, https://frictionlessdata.io/specs/patterns/#data-package-version

Answer (score 8):

[Dataverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataverse) uses [the following dataset versioning strategy](https://web.archive.org/web/20141012001937/http://datascience.iq.harvard.edu:80/blog/dataset-versioning-dataverse-40-beta):

[image]

Comment: The link above is a 404 but the image can now be found at http://guides.dataverse.org/en/4.8.6/user/dataset-management.html#dataset-versions

Answer (score 3):

The [Digital Curation Centre](http://www.dcc.ac.uk/) guide on [how to cite datasets and link to publications](http://www.dcc.ac.uk/resources/how-guides/cite-datasets) gives a [good summary](http://www.dcc.ac.uk/resources/how-guides/cite-datasets#sec:versions) to the various approaches to dataset versioning from the viewpoint of repository managers, and links to further information.

Comment: Please provide a précis of the content you linked in this post, as links may change and web resources become inaccessible over time.